# Use sphinx with Flask and preserve formatting

Tags: flask, python-sphinx

I generate some Python documentation with Sphinx.  If I go to the build/html directory and open index.html directly, I get Sphinx formatting.

If I try to serve the same page Flask with the following code, I get the page but all the Sphinx formatting is gone:

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/help')
def help():
    return send_from_directory('/sphinx/build/html', 'index.html')
```

I am calling Flask directly with app.run in debug mode.  This is how I like it. I know how to set it up in Apache but I don't want to run Apache.  Is it possible to serve Sphinx inside Flask and still get the formatting, or do I absolutely have to run a web serve like Apache?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what "Sphinx formatting is gone" means, but its likely that there are css or js files that aren't getting served properly. When you visit your website in developer mode, are there any requests that get denied?

Comment: what does your directory structure look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your Sphinx documentation folder with generated html files `/sphinx/build` under the static folder `./static/sphinx/build`.

Then use Jinja to link it:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='sphinx/build/html/index.html') }}">Documentation</a>
```

The resulting url on your local server will look similar to this:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/sphinx/build/html/index.html`

When your app is deployed, replace the new directory with a symbolic link, so   needn't copy the `/sphinx/build` folder every time the documentation is built.